# Boltzmann's Entropy formula clarification

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Isn't the number of micro states for a particular macro state infinite? In a classical sense, I can rotate the velocity vector of a particle in infinitely many ways, so the number of micro states must be infinite. I can't understand why it shouldn't be. Please give me a way to imagine this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the number os micro states for a particular macro state in continuous (classical) systems such as the one you describe is indeed infinite, but it is infinite in the same way the number of points in a surface is infinite: the points are infinite but we can define a measure of how large the surface it is, an thus, "how many points it has", in some sense. 
Indeed, the "number of microstates" function :

$\omega (E,\alpha ,N)=\frac{1}{h^{3N}}\int dq dp  \delta (E-H_N)$

Is no other thing than (a multiple of) **the area, in the phase space, of the surface made up by the states which have energy E.**
This is more clearly seen keeping in mind that each state is a point in phase space.
Thus, even if the points are infinite, the $\omega (E,\alpha ,N)$ function gives us a meaningful measure of how many there are.